# Error compiling code for Arduino/Genuino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, compilation-errors, avr-gcc

> Arduino: 1.8.6 Hourly Build 2017/10/20 02:33 (Windows 10), Board:
>   "Arduino/Genuino Uno"
>
> c:\users\hp\desktop\arduino-nightly\hardware\tools\avr\bin../lib/gcc/avr/4.9.2/../../../../avr/bin/ar.exe:
>   unable to rename 'core\core.a'; reason: Permission denied
>
> exit status 1 Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno.
>
> This report would have more information with "Show verbose output
>   during compilation" option enabled in File -> Preferences.

Please help me fix this problem. This is my code:

```
int redled = 6;
int yellowled = 9;
int greenled = 12;

void setup() {
  pinMode (6, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (9, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (12, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite (redled, 1);
  delay(9000);
  digitalWrite (redled, 0); //stopped
  digitalWrite (yellowled, 1);
  delay (3000); // yellowled lights for 3 sec.
  digitalWrite (yellowled, 0);
  digitalWrite (greenled, 1);
  delay (9000);
  digitalWrite (greenled, 0);// greenled starts flashing
  delay (500);
  digitalWrite (greenled, 1);
  delay (500);
  digitalWrite (greenled, 0);
  delay (500);
  digitalWrite (greenled, 1);
  delay (500);
  digitalWrite (greenled, 0);
  delay (500);
  digitalWrite (greenled, 1);
  delay (500);
  digitalWrite (greenled, 0);
  delay (500);
  digitalWrite (greenled, 1);
  delay (500);
  digitalWrite (greenled, 0);
}
```

Comment: Why are you running an hourly build? What did you expect?

Comment: There are some reports of this error in the Arduino IDE issue tracker: https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues/5616 and https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues/4683 where it was found to be caused by antivirus software

Comment: Explanation is in your question : c:\users\hp\desktop\arduino-nightly\hardware\tools\avr\bin../lib/gcc/avr/4.9.2/../../../../avr/bin/ar.exe: unable to rename 'core\core.a'; reason: Permission denied

Comment: please use digitalWrite (redled, 1); HIGH and LOW in digitalwrite instead of 1 and 0.

Comment: In what way does this answer the question?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is just what the error message says it is.

> c:\users\hp\desktop\arduino-nightly\hardware\tools\avr\bin../lib/gcc/avr/4.9.2/../../../../avr/bin/ar.exe: unable to rename 'core\core.a'; reason: Permission denied

When you are compiling your code the compilation process is trying to rename a file called core.a (.a means a library). I'm guessing it is doing this because you have changed the board type and it needs to compile the library for that type of board.

You don't have permission to change this file. This could be because:

1. You don't have Windows security permission.
2. The file is in use already.
3. It's because you have installed it on your desktop.

The easiest to check is 2, reboot you machine and start only one instance of the IDE and try again. If it works, something (don't ask what) was accessing the file.

If it doesn't work you need to change the security permissions of the parent folder and all sub folders and files. You will need to Google how to do that, and you will need to search for core/core.a.